# Vertical alignment of an array with numbered list

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, arrays, exam

please refer to the following scenarios:

[image: Case 1]

and

[image: Case 2]

The first case is generated by the following part of the script:

```
\question[5+2]
        Let $ (X,d) $ be a metric space and $ A\subseteq X $. \textit{Boundary} of $ A $ is defined as $ \partial A=\bar{A}\setminus A^{\circ} $. Show that,
        \begin{parts}
%3.a.
            \part[5]
                \[ \begin{array}{rcl}
                \partial A  &=& (A^{\circ}\cup \ext A)^{c}\\[1ex]
                &=& \{x\in X:\forall\d>0, N_{\d}(x)\cap A\ne\emptyset\text{ and }N_{\d}(x)\cap A^{c}\ne\emptyset\}. 
                \end{array} \tag*{\parbox{1pt}{\droppoints}} \]
```

and the second instance is generated by

```
\question[5+2]
        Let $ (X,d) $ be a metric space and $ A\subseteq X $. \textit{Boundary} of $ A $ is defined as $ \partial A=\bar{A}\setminus A^{\circ} $. Show that,
        \begin{parts}
%3.a.
            \part[5]
                $\begin{array}{rcl}
                \partial A  &=& (A^{\circ}\cup \ext A)^{c}\\[1ex]
                &=& \{x\in X:\forall\d>0, N_{\d}(x)\cap A\ne\emptyset\text{ and }N_{\d}(x)\cap A^{c}\ne\emptyset\}. 
                \end{array}$\droppoints
```

What I want is to align the first line of the array with the question number **(a)**. How can I achieve that?

I am using `exam` class. Here is my preamble.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{exam}
\usepackage[left=0.25in,right=0.75in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,footskip=.15in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, amsfonts}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{lastpage,refcount}
\footer{}{\small\thepage}{\ifodd\value{page}\relax
    \if\thepage\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}\relax
    \else \tiny {\mbox{\kern\dimexpr+4.75in\relax}}\boxed{\textbf{Turn Over}}
    \fi
    \fi}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\setlength\@rightmargin{0.5in}
\patchcmd\setup@point@toks{\llap{\padded@point@block}}{\rlap{\padded@point@block}}{}{}
\patchcmd\droppoints{\llap{\padded@point@block}}{\rlap{\padded@point@block}}{}{}
\patchcmd\droptotalpoints{\llap{\total@block}}{\rlap{\total@block}}{}{}
\patchcmd\droptotalbonuspoints{\llap{\bonustotal@block}}{\rlap{\bonustotal@block}}{}{}
\makeatother


\marksnotpoints
\bracketedpoints
\pointsdroppedatright


\renewcommand\partlabel{(\textbf{\alph{partno}})}
\renewcommand{\thesubpart}{(\textit{\roman{subpart}})}
\renewcommand{\subpartlabel}{\thesubpart}
\renewcommand\questionlabel{\textbf{\thequestion.}}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\renewcommand{\a}{\alpha}
\renewcommand{\b}{\beta}
\newcommand{\g}{\gamma}
\renewcommand{\d}{\delta}
\newcommand{\e}{\epsilon}
\DeclareMathOperator{\interior}{int}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ext}{ext}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert #1 \right\rVert}
```

Comment: Try the second solution, but using `\begin{array}[t]{rcl}`.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks. Worked like charm!

Comment: @Bernard an answer?

Comment: @cmhughes: I don't think it's really necessary. There other answers already mentioning this parameter.